# Should "drinking" be synonym for "nightlife" or "alcohol" (or something else)?

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-synonyms

[drinking](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drinking) is currently synonym for [alcohol](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alcohol). I was just wondering if [nightlife](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nightlife) would be a better "synonym target" for it. What opine you?

Consider how travel guides often use "Sleeping", "Eating", and "Drinking". You can participate in drinking and nightlife without actually focusing on alcohol (although, yes, as a Finn it feels strange to write that ;-P).

As an example:
["what parts of town to visit for dinner/drinks?"](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/7231/two-nights-in-baltimore-md-what-parts-of-town-to-visit-for-dinner-drinks) — Trying to tag that [drinking](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drinking), it got automatically changed to [alcohol](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alcohol) which I think is poorer choice of tags... (So I manually re-tagged it.)

Related: perhaps there should be a [bars](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bars) tag (c.f. [restaurants](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restaurants))?

Answer (score 4):

I am not convinced 'drinking' should be a synonym at all but am certain it should not be a synonym of [nightlife](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nightlife). Looking at all the questions tagged [alcohol](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alcohol) (I can't differentiate whether that was what was chosen or 'drinking' was) far less than 10% have anything to do with the time of day.

For the time being at least I suggest sticking with the status quo.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about night life, but drinking as a synonym for alcohol seems to me as arbitrary and unjustified as if we change "eating" into a synonym for "pizza".